# Given certain parameters, are there any risks with Android's USB Debugging?

Tags: android, usb

Assuming:

1. You control access to an Android device
2. You never connect that Android device to a malware-infected system via a USB cable

Are there any risks with keeping USB Debugging always enabled on the Android device?

If your answer is Android version-dependent, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

If you have total control of the device and are very careful what connects to it then there's no risk in leaving debugging on at all times. Leaving USB debugging on is risky when you do not have control. So if you have a phone you use purely for development and testing then leaving USB debugging on makes sense. If you use your personal phone for development then it is recommended you turn off debugging when you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks. If you have total control over your personal phone, what is the risk of leaving USB Debugging on all the time?

Comment: If you have total control all the time then it's not a risk. Few people have total control all the time though -  if you ever lost it or it gets stolen it would be much easier to compromise. How big a risk that is depends on where you live and your lifestyle.

Comment: Thanks.  So if USB Debugging is enabled, it makes it easier to get past the lock screen?  If so, that might be a worthwhile thing to add to your answer.